# need help to displaying image to another page from FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new at ASP.NET C#.

Here i got a problem with displaying an image. I'll explain what am i doing here and where i got problem.

I'm creating one page with FileUpload control. 
Just like other forum does i got a button Preview. When user clicks on, it shows what user has written and what image he or she is uploaded.

So i suppose to create one page called Preview.aspx and it's blank.
second i have a page called Administration. at that page i have FileUpload control. 
Even there are few textbox, label... other controls, but there are not so usefull right here. 
I named FileUpload control as fuImage.

i show you what i have written at event btnPreview_Click.

```
string img;   
if (fuImage.HasFile){
    fuImage.SaveAs(@"C:\Temp\" + fuImage.FileName);
    img = "<img alt=\"sd\" src=\"" + @"C:\Temp\" + fuImage.FileName.ToString() + "\"></img>";
    }else
    img = "";

    Functions.displayOnCommon = "<h3>" + tbSubject.Text + "</h3><hr/>"+img+"<p>" + tbPost.Text + "</p>";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "", "window.open('Preview.aspx','Graph','height=400,width=800');",
```

I'm saving users image at server and use that image to show as preview.
That Functions.displayOnCommon is just simple string declared at another location and it's not so necessary.

Here is Preview.aspx's backstage C# code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreview(Functions.displayOnCommon);
    }
void printPreview(string texts) {
        Response.Write("<div class=\"preview\">" + texts + "</div>");
    }
```

It shows me whole texts, but not image. 
Sorry for my bad English explanation. 
I'm just learning English and ASP.NET C#. :D

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing but fundamentally you cannot reference a local, server file path from the browser.

```
img = "<img alt=\"sd\" src=\"" + @"C:\Temp\" + fuImage.FileName.ToString() + "\"></img>";
```

You will instead need to reference a server endpoint that in turn loads the image and streams it back to the client and there are a number of ways to accomplish that.

Comment: yeah. I know that too. But all i found solution is right above us.can you please share me how to make it simple and fast and easy please :D